# Slightly Overstaying In Thailand Due To miss count (31 days)

Tags: visas, thailand, overstaying

I bought a ticket to Thailand I arrive in Bangkok September 2nd, and leave October second. I essentially fly out on my 31st day in the country. I also have bought a one way ticket to Laos near the end of my trip to spend a few days there then was considering just crossing back over the border by bus.

I am not a little concerned that I may have an issue without having a visa (although I am going to leave the country for a day or two or more). I have just read so many different views on this. I tried to reach the consult, which seems to be quite challenging. I also live about 7 hours away from the nearest one and I am not in a window now to apply by mail. Any advice?

Comment: `I am not a little concerned` - you mean **now**?

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is about how to avoid problems with potentially overstaying the visa and what the OP can do now. The other question concerns a traveler who has already overstayed in Thailand. I believe the answer to one does not relate to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You don't list your nationality, but if you are from one of the 55 countries that qualify for visa exempt entry, you will get a 30 day entry stamp upon arrival and then again when you return from Laos.

The issue will be the airline you fly from home to Thailand with as they are supposed to check that you are leaving Thailand before 30 days.  Normally an air ticket is required for this.  As you didn't really specify what your ticket to Laos was, the trip to Laos may or may not satisfy the airline staff.

Comment: I bought an airline ticket through air asia, and I am U.S. resident so I am allotted the visa exempt. I have just been confused due to so much contradiction on the net. Will my airline ticket showing I am leaving the country be enough for the airline to not give me issue?

Comment: I bought a one way airline ticket to Laos. I think I will probably just bus back across the border as it is towards the end of my trip. Will the one way airline ticket to Laos suffice or do I need to get a visa which would entail a 7 hour drive each way to Los Angeles at this point. Which seems a bit excessive if this plan ticket would suffice proof.

Comment: @Jordan - Yes an airline ticket is the preferred form of POOT, so your flight to Laos will work just fine.